# Response is committing and doFilter chain is broken

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, servlet-filters

In order this is what I need to happen:

Request on `blah.com/test`

1. ServletFilter A - creates profile, then calls `chain.doFilter`
2. ServletFilter B (is skipped because url pattern doesn't match)
3. Servlet -  alters the profile, `repsonse.setStatus` & `response.addHeader("Location", target)`
4. ServletFilter A - should create a cookie based on the profile

What is actually happening:

1. ServletFilter A - creates profile, then calls `chain.doFilter`
2. ServletFilter B (is skipped because url pattern doesn't match)
3. Servlet -  alters the profile, `repsonse.setStatus` & `response.addHeader("Location", target)`
4. Redirect is committed and ServletFilter A does not complete tasks

I think this may be related to the dispatcher values that you can set in the ServletFilter configs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the response is getting committed when it reaches `ServletFilter A` at `Step 4`. Once the response is committed, i.e, headers are written to  the client, you cannot do operations which requires adding headers. The operations like adding cookies.

If you want the response not to be committed till `Step 4` try wrapping `HttpServletResponse` and returning your custom output stream which buffers the data till it reaches `step 4` and then commits the response.

**Here is the sample code :**

```
public class ResponseBufferFilter implements Filter
{
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
{
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
   FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    BufferResponseWrapper wrapper = new BufferResponseWrapper(httpResponse);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, resposneWrapper);
    response.getOutputStream().write(wrapper .getWrapperBytes());
}

public void destroy()
{
}

private final class BufferResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{

    MyServletOutputStream stream = new MyServletOutputStream();

    public BufferResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
    {
        super(httpServletResponse);
    }

    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        return stream;
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
    {
        return new PrintWriter(stream);
    }

    public byte[] getWrapperBytes()
    {
        return stream.getBytes();
    }
}

private final class MyServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream
{
    private ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        out.write(b);
    }

    public byte[] getBytes()
    {
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Then after `response.getOutputStream().write(wrapper .getWrapperBytes());` I should be able to write cookies to the response? Or before that?

Comment: You should do before writing to the actual response.

Comment: You solution worked fine where there is no response payload. But, it breaks when there's a respons epayload body. Could use a hand. Thanks.

Comment: This caches the whole response to memory, which might not be desirable. Here is another solution which worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/67272419/662084

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. Anyway it's important to note that, just in case the buffered response size is smaller than 8KB, it won't work unless you flush the response before u call `getWrapperBytes()`.

This is due to servlet-api internal implementation.