# Spring Post Method with Unit return type returns 200 instead of 204

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

When executing a method with return type Unit I would expect the spring to put 204 NO CONTENT on the status code in the response, however it always returns 200 OK. Is there any way  to change this behaviour in a global away? I don't want to add ResponseStatus annotations to every Unit method.

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/{role:(?:veterinarian\\b|admin\\b)}")
class EmployeeController(
        private val userService: UserService
) {

    @PostMapping(consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE])
    fun hire(@RequestBody employeeDTO: EmployeeDTO, @PathVariable role: String): Unit {
        if (employeeDTO.user_role != role)
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        else
            userService.addNewUser(EmployeeDAO.build(employeeDTO))
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I ended up using a filter to check if the content type was undefined when that Status Response was 200 OK and it seems to work.

This is the filter code

```
@Component
public class NoContentFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        if (httpServletResponse.getContentType() == null ||
                httpServletResponse.getContentType().equals("")) {
            if ( httpServletResponse.getStatus() == 200 ) {
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396884/return-http-204-on-null-with-spring-restcontroller There are several suggestions that might be helpful to you

Comment: I will try an adaption of the answer with the Filter. I added a check to ensure that that response status was 200,  so that it does not interfere with other reponses where there the body can be empty(like an error)

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows configuring global behavior for controllers via @ControllerAdvice

> Classes annotated with @ControllerAdvice can contain @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute annotated methods, and these methods will apply to @RequestMapping methods across all controller hierarchies as opposed to the controller hierarchy within which they are declared.

Usually, we use it to handle exceptions globally with `@ExceptionHandler` but it is not your case. (`@InitBinder`, `@ModelAttribute` too)

There is `ResponseBodyAdvice` but there is no `ResponseStatusAdvice`

So it seems **there is no direct solution**

**Workaround:**

It is a pretty dirty hack and I would really recommend you just use @ResponseStatus each time but if you really want to solve that problem globally then:

You can combine error processing and ResponseBodyAdvice

You should create an exception class

```
class NoContentException: RuntimeException()
```

create a handler for it. It should be invoked after `@ControllerAdvice` which will throw NoContentException so it has `@Order(1)`

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(1)
class NoContentErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoContentException::class)
    fun handleNoContent() = ResponseEntity.noContent().build<Unit>()
}
```

and at the end create a response body advice which throws the actual exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(0)
class ThrowingNoContentExceptionResponseBodyAdvice : ResponseBodyAdvice<Unit> {
    override fun supports(returnType: MethodParameter, converterType: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>): Boolean {
        return returnType.parameterType == Void.TYPE
    }

    override fun beforeBodyWrite(
        body: Unit?,
        returnType: MethodParameter,
        selectedContentType: MediaType,
        selectedConverterType: Class<out HttpMessageConverter<*>>,
        request: ServerHttpRequest,
        response: ServerHttpResponse
    ): Unit? {
        throw NoContentException()
    }
}
```

So it works like:
request -> method with Unit response call -> the advice throwing the exception -> the advice processing the exception and converting it to NO_CONTENT status

Comment: I was hoping that there was a solution using `@ControllerAdvice`. I will reconsider using `@ResponseStatus` or try to do It with a `OncePerRequestFilter`,  since I agree with you that is a really dirty way of solving it. Thank you for your answer