# Java Servlet Filter - Modify response headers based on status

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I'm trying to write a servlet filter that will add headers to the response depending on the status of the request. I know I have to wrap the response with a HttpServletResponseWrapper before passing to the `chain.doFilter` but the headers never get sent, so I'm obviously missing something very obvious.

Code looks something like:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
   HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
   HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

   chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

   if(responseWrapper.getStatus() < 400)
   {
      responseWrapper.addHeader("X-Custom-Foobar", "abc");
   }
}
```

Is there something I have to capture in the wrapper to prevent the response from going out to the client until the check is complete?

Answer (score 2):

So the frustrating part about this spec is that you have to completely intercept the `ServletOutputStream` and buffer it.  I ended up following the example here :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027170/76343

The base class `HttpServletResponseWrapper` is a complete passthrough and as soon as the output stream is closed, all further modifications to the response are mute.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *extend* `HttpResponseWrapper()` and override the appropriate methods. Just using a vanilla `HttpResponseWrapper` by itself accomplishes exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible. But because after calling `chain.doFilter(request, response)` the response is already committed, we have to set the headers after receiving the status code, but before the response is committed. Here is an example:

```
public class HeadersFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                                                                                             ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        chain.doFilter(request, new ResponseWrapper(response));
    }

    public static class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
        public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc) {
            super.setStatus(sc);

            // SET YOUR HEADERS HERE
            // setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually run this? `setStatus(int sc)` isn't ever called. So no headers can be set.

Comment: @PaulUszak Not only have I run this, but I have code in production very similar to this. If `setStatus(int sc)` is not called for you, how do you suppose response gets returned without any status?

Comment: Sorry mate, I put a print statement below `super.setStatus(sc);` and it is not called on my machine. The wrapper is created, but the method isn't called. If you then add wacky custom headers, they are not added. I'm running Tomcat 9. Doesn't matter as I've resolved it another way :-)

Answer (score 0):

The order of this code is inverted:

```
   chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

   if(responseWrapper.getStatus() < 400)
   {
      responseWrapper.addHeader("X-Custom-Foobar", "abc");
   }
```

Try this instead:

```
   if(responseWrapper.getStatus() < 400)
   {
      responseWrapper.addHeader("X-Custom-Foobar", "abc");
   }

   chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
```

The `doFilter` method does not return to your method until after the response has been sent on the wire.